# subgrouping within a group by using the quantile

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to divide samples into subgroups within a group by using a quantile.

For instance,

```
   id          value      desired column
    1             1               low   
    1             2               low   
    1             3               mid   
    1             4               high   
    1             5               high   
    2             10              high  
    2             20              mid   
    2             30              low
```

I have `id` and `value` columns and for each id, I would like do grouping based on the quantile of values such that top 30% of value would be `"high"` , bottom 30% would be `"low"`  and rest would be all `"mid"`.

Any suggenstion? in R (if there is a good way with using dplyr package, it is good, otherwise still okay)

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df = df %>% mutate(group = cut(value, breaks=quantile(value, probs=c(0.2,0.8), labels=c("low","mid","high"))` or in base R, `df$group = cut(df$value, breaks=quantile(df$value, probs=c(0.2,0.8), labels=c("low","mid","high"))`. If you want the quantile groupings separately by `id`, then add `group_by(id)` before the `mutate` step.

Comment: @eipi10, your code doesn't quite work for me. I could get it to work if I modified `breaks` as `c(0,quantile(value,probs=c(0.2,0.8)),max(value))`

Comment: Thank you eipi !